# Redirect sub domain to another sub domain with the same sub folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I want to redirect sub domain to another sub domain by htaccess code for exmaple

if someone visit the following link

```
games.domain.com/data
```

will reditect him to

```
games.domain.net/data
```

notice : i already redirect the main domain with the following .htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^games\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(data(?:/.*|))$ http://games.domain.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Did you put this in your root .htaccess on games.domain.com? What URL did you try to test?

Comment: it's not only .htaccess in the web directory , i have another .htaccess in the main directory of the website , here is the .htaccess code in the main site i add your code insite it not creating another .htaccess in the games directory

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^games\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(data(?:/.*|))$ http://games.domain.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: Very difficult to read code from comment, can you please edit your question and add code there.

Comment: i update my question with this code , i just add your code below my code and it dosen't work at all

Comment: no it's not that domain but i am sure that both sub domains working @anbhava

Comment: Alright try keeping my suggested code on top of your .htaccess before any other rule. Also tell me what URL did you try to test?

Comment: it redirect to games.domain.net/games , i don't want to be redirect with games folder only the subdomain and sub folder in case of someone have a link for subdomain like games.domain.com/data will redirect it to games.domain.net/data

Comment: Most likely it is conflict of other rules since my code is not redirecting to `/games` above.

Comment: what URL did you use to test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36421/discussion-between-ilinux85-and-anubhava)

Comment: Hi sorry I missed your chat invite. Did you problem get solved?